# Opendaylight: How to get a row from OVSDB table

Tags: opendaylight, openvswitch

I'm having a hard time getting a specific value out of the OVSDB using Opendaylight.

I can get the information fine using the JSON-RPC call directly to the OVSDB host but I haven't found a way to consult the OVSDB database from ODL.

Specifically, I'm trying to get the statistics of any given port on a given switch but so far I haven't found it yet.

I'm not using ODL as Openflow controller, just as OVSDB manager.

Answer (score 0):

is what you want (the statistics) available by polling the operational
topology after your ovsdb node is connected?

do a GET to http://${ODL_IP}:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology

here's an example output in [ODL csit](https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/vex-yul-odl-jenkins-1/ovsdb-csit-1node-upstream-southbound-all-nitrogen/293/log.html.gz#s1-s5-t12-k3-k1-k2)

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the interface statistics in that output, the statistics are packet_sent, byte_set etc.. per interface.